# Reading data from the device?

Tags: java, gps, netty

Am developing a Netty application. In that am reading the data packets from the client. But there is one device called Teltonika. This device first sends the IMEI number and once we acknowledge, it sends the TrackPacket .

But the problem here is that it sends the correct IMEI number but the TarckPacket being sent remains in an unreadable format. Please help me .

```
'IMEI NO: [0, 15, 51, 53, 50, 56, 52, 56, 48, 50, 50, 55, 57, 49, 55, 49, 53]'
```

The  device sending IMEI number, is in correct format but the below tracking packet is not int the correct format.

**Tracking Packet:**

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -61, 8, 4, 0, 0, 1, 53, -117, 86, 80, -56, 0, 46, 60, 22, -128, 7, -60, -27, 40, 3, -118, 1, 92, 10, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 9, 0, 23, 10, 0, 13, 24, 0, 0, 1, -57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 53, -117, 85, 101, -18, 0, 46, 60, 22, -128, 7, -60, -27, -112, 3, -119, 1, 92, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 9, 0, 27, 10, 0, 10, 24, 0, 0, 1, -57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 53, -117, 84, 123, 21, 0, 46, 60, 22, -128, 7, -60, -27, -112, 3, -121, 1, 92, 8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 9, 0, 27, 10, 0, 12, 24, 0, 0, 1, -57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 53, -117, 83, -115, -78, 0, 46, 60, 22, -128, 7, -60, -27, -48, 3, -121, 1, 92, 11 ]

**What I have done:**

```
StringBuffer sbs = new StringBuffer(); 
buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
while(buf.readable()) 
{
sbs.append((char) buf.readByte()); 
} 
msg = sbs.toString();
System.out.println(msg);
byte[] request = new byte[] { 0x01 };    
e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(request)); 
System.out.flush();
```

Comment: StringBuffer sbs = new StringBuffer();
buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
 while(buf.readable()) {
    sbs.append((char) buf.readByte());
       }
 msg = sbs.toString();    System.out.println(msg);

byte[] request = new byte[] { 0x01 };        e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(request));
System.out.flush(); AM able to send acknowledgement the device also understands. but device is sending track packet am not able to read.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a mobile gsm or cdma device then search for "AT Commands"
fire these commands COM ports, that returns desired result for fired commands..